# How to match xml node of Settings file in C# application

Tags: c#, regex

My C# code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="ICTRExchange.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <ICTRExchange.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ServerIP" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServerPort" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
```

How to match using regular expression in C#.
I try regular expression in below. but It is not proper operation.

example

My target node is `"ServerPort"`

```
var regex = new Regex("<setting name=\"ServerPort\"(.*?)</setting>");
regex.match(xmlstring)
```

Comment: why do you want to read your cofiguration file with regex? it is non-sense. you can use ConfigurationManager, you can parse with XML. why regex?

Comment: @Simonare It is using the other process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing mark up alnguage with regex is very bad idea (see: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) - it's aboout HTML, but also applies to XML).

Instead, you could use XML library provided in .NET, like `System.Xml`.

Here's code snippet you could build your application on (I stored your XML in `testxml.xml` file):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
  xml.Load(@"C:/users/MyUser/desktop/testxml.xml");
  var settings = xml.SelectNodes("configuration/userSettings/ICTRExchange.Properties.Settings")[0].ChildNodes;
  XmlNode settingsWithServerPort = null;
  foreach (XmlNode node in settings)
    if (node.Attributes["name"].Value == "ServerPort")
      settingsWithServerPort = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
<setting.*?>[\w\W]+?<\/setting>
```

> Explanation

- `<setting.*?>` - Matches `<setting` followed by anything except new line followed by `>`.
- `[\w\W]+?` - Matches anything one or more time. (lazy mode).
- `<\/setting>` - Matches `</setting>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fCTzpF/2/)